# Does the point lie inside a dihedral angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification

The dihedral angle between two planes can be determined by taking the dot product of their vectors. Hence, we have to find the angle between the vectors of the planes: the product of two vectors is equal to the product of their magnitudes multiplied by the cosine of the angle between them.

The vector of the first plane is $\left \langle 1,-10,9 \right \rangle$, the second equals $\left \langle 3,-7,-4 \right \rangle$, then
$$\left \langle 1,-10,9 \right \rangle \cdot  \left \langle 3,-7,-4 \right \rangle = 3 - 70 - 36 = -103$$
The cosine of the angle between the two planes is
$$\cos \alpha =-\frac{103}{\sqrt{1+10^2+9^2}\cdot \sqrt{3^2+7^2+4^2}}=-\frac{103}{\sqrt{98}\cdot \sqrt{74}}$$

Since the angle between the two planes is greater than 90 degrees, the dihedral angle is obtuse. Consequently, the point $(-3,4,5)$ lies inside the dihedral angle

*Can anyone tell me if my reasoning was correct and if I got the answer right?*

Comment: Two planes form four dihedral angles. Which is the right one?

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Yes, you are right, the two planes form 4 dihedral angles. Our task is to see if this point lies in one of the four dihedral angles

Comment: Those four dihedral angles span the whole space, hence...

Comment: If you want to know in WHICH dihedral angle (of the four) that point lies, then you should rephrase your question and explain more clearly your problem.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know in which of the four dihedral angles this point lies, if it lies in any of the four corners at all

Comment: Do you have the equations of the two planes?

Comment: As I wrote above, those four dihedra cover all space, hence either the point lies in one of them, or it lies on one of the planes.

Comment: HINT. If the equation of a plane is $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $P$ is a point, then $f(P)\gtrless 0$ if $P$ lies in either half-space having that plane as border.